# Classes in a web application dll crash

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll, web-applications

I converted a ASP.Net website to ASP.Net web app and changed the framework from 2.0 to 3.5

The web application works fine in Visual studio. However, If I compile the app in a dll, and try to reuse its middle layer in another web project, All the classes that have a static variable crash. Code like:

```
public static string myString = "Something";
```

However if I convert it to a property like this:

```
public static string myString {get{return "Something";}}
```

, it works. Anyone knows the reason?

Answer (score 0):

I may be mistaken, but I think it's because static variables are interned at compilation time.

Have you recompiled the other web project before using it ?  That could be the reason. (but again, I have no certainty)